# How to verify an Azure OAuth Access JWT Token in native Javascript without using a library?

Tags: javascript, azure, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have an OAuth Access Token (its from Azure). I would like to verify the signature.

I've decoded the token

Header

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "abc123",
  "kid": "abc123"
}
```

And the payload

```
{
  "aud": "api://xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/",
  "iat": 1580132587,
  "nbf": 1580132587,
  "exp": 1580136487,
  "acct": 0,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "appid": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxf",
  "appidacr": "0",
  "ipaddr": "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy",
  "name": "test",
  "oid": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "scp": "user_impersonation",
  "sub": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "tid": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "unique_name": "test@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com",
  "upn": "test@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com",
  "uti": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

(After verifying the intended audience (aud)) I need to verify the signature. To do that I first need to calculate the signature. To do that

1. I need to call the Azure metadata document to confirm the public key in the header.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

2. From that I get the public keys (JWKS URI), e.g.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/discovery/v2.0/keys

3. This gives me an array

   ```
   [{
       "kty": "RSA",
       "use": "sig",
       "kid": "abc123",
       "x5t": "abc123",
       "n": "...",
       "e": "...",
       "x5c": [..."],
       "issuer": " https: //login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/v2.0"
       }, {
       "kty": "RSA",
       "use": "sig",
       "kid": "...",
       "x5t": "...",
       "n": "....",
       "e": "...",
       "x5c": ["."],
       "issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/v2.0"
       },
   ]
   ```
4. I check that `kid` and `x5t` match the fields in the header.

**Questions**

1. How to calculate the actual signature? In my case the signing algorithm is RS256, so I got to do something like this

`RSASHA256(  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +   base64UrlEncode(payload), public_key)`

2. What is the public_key?
3. And in native Javascript is there a function RSASHA256 ?

Answer (score 2):

Get the x5t that matches the kid of the received token. That is the public key, though it typically needs translating to PEM format.

Most people then use a certified library to validate the signature with the public key. [Here is some code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts) that does that to validate an Azure token.

By native JavaScript I assume you mean NodeJS, since access tokens are validated by APIs and not UIs.

Ultimately I believe libraries like jsonwebtoken call underlying operating system crypto code - not for the faint hearted ..